# Download link not returning proper byte stream

Tags: asp.net

I'm retrieving a file from a database server and allowing the user to download it.  The problem is, I'm not getting the same byte stream out as I've read from the server.

I have confirmed (through lots of response.write) that I've received the right array of bytes, they're in the right order, etc...

Here's the code for the download st.FileContents is a byte[]:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
               "attachment; filename=" + st.FileName);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", st.FileSize.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.Write(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
                .GetString(st.FileContents));  // Problem line
        Response.End();
```

I've tried a few ways of converting that byte [] to a string, and none give the results I need. Instead of the expected stream of bytes as:

`FF D8 FF E0 1E D0 4A 46 58 58 00 10 FF D8 FF DB`

(yes, that's the start of a jpeg image)

I wind up with something like:

`C3 BF C3 98 C3 BF C3 A0 1E C3 90 4A 46 58 58 00`

The first 6 bytes get mangled into 10 completely different bytes.  What gives?

**Edit**

The answer is, of course, to use BinaryWrite instead of Write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be treating binary data as strings. In this example, ASCII encoding only supports characters in range 0-127, so any bytes that do not fall into that range are treated as invalid and replaced with a question mark. Use `HttpResponse.BinaryWrite` instead:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(st.FileContents);
```

Comment: Of course, after monkeying with this for half an hour... moments after I hit "post" I see the BinaryWrite method.  D'oh.